# Java requireNonNull always returns true when Unit Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Im trying to implement *requireNonNull* check on my object when Unit testing using JUnit, Im expecting an Exception to be throw but never is...

```
public TheClass(final String name) {
    requireNonNull(!StringUtils.isBlank(name), "name cannot be null/empty");

    this.name = name;
}
```

//Test

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testInstantiateWithNullName() {
    new TheClass(null);
}
```

Any Ideas....

Iv also ran the test with 'expected = NullPointerException.class'

Comment: What does `!StringUtils.isBlank` do?

Comment: Checks that the String is not blank...

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, your `StringUtils.isBlank` returns a `boolean` representing whether the given `String` is `null` or empty.

You're passing that `boolean` value to `requireNonNull`. Since that value isn't `null`, no exception is thrown.

Pass the `name` directly

```
requireNonNull(name, "name cannot be null/empty");
```

Though you should probably change the error message since this only checks if the argument is `null`. It does not consider the argument as a `String` and check if it is empty.

Comment: Aside from requireNonNull iv to make sure if its not null that its also not empty...without the use og Guava

Comment: @Ronando Write your own method. I'm not aware of a static JDK method to check if a `String` is empty.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Right, unless `name` is `null`.

Comment: but we check it before.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use

```
if(name != null)
```

You're passing a boolean value to a method that will return false if null is not received, therefore it will always consider it to be non-null. If you really want to use requireNonNull then you can do

```
requireNonNull(name, "name cannot be null");
```

However, I think what you really want is

```
if(name != null && !name.isEmpty())
```

Answer (score 0):

With guava you can do:

```
checkArgument(StringUtils.isNotBlank(name), "name cannot be null/empty");
```

Note that this throws an IllegalArgumentException if isNotBlank is false;